# Browser resize does not affect HTML content

Tags: javascript, html, css

so I have developed this website which works fine in the laptop screen when the browser is maximized. But if I resize the browser, the content seems to shrink in order to fit in the browser.
What can I do to not let this happen? So than even when the browser is re-sized, the background content is till the same(ofcouse only the content coming in the browser's current re-sized window will be shown).

An example is this :-
[image]

Live link :- www.amiteshgrover.com/dev

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: You need to make your website responsive. What is happening now is normal. Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: Honestly, I don't understand what you need

P.s. i've found a bug on the menu, when you fastly switch the cursor over the menu voices. Try to pu a .stop() (jquery function) in chain before you mouse-over animations!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `min-width` on your container divs and high-level elements. Another way would be to set a `min-width` and `max-width` on the containers and a fixed size on the contents.

Keep in mind, this does not make your page responsive as that would include automatically moving elements and changing layout as well.

Answer (score 0):

first off try and enclose all of your javascript within

```
$(document).ready(function () {

});
```

because I am getting an error at the console. Probably because jquery hasn't finished loading yet.

```
(function() {
    // the line below throws an error
    var quotes = $(".quotes");
```